# I am trying to return combined rows in the same table based on a key in a second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I probably haven't explained this very well in the title but I have two tables. Here is a simple version.

**channel_data**

```
entry_id   channel_id   first_name   last_name   model   other_fields
1          4            John         Smith
2          4            Jane         Doe
3          4            Bill         Evans
4          15                                    235
5          15                                    765
6          15                                    543
7          15                                    723
8          15                                    354
9          15                                    976
10         1                                             xxx
11         2                                             yyy
12         3                                             123
```

**channel_titles**

```
entry_id   author_id   channel_id
1          101         4
2          102         4
3          103         4
4          101         15
5          101         15
6          101         15
7          102         15
8          102         15
9          103         15
10         101         1
11         102         2
12         103         3
```

I am not able to re-model the data unfortunately.

I need to list all the rows with a channel_id 15 from channel_data and beside them the first_name and last_name which has the same author_id from channel_titles.

What I want to return is this:

```
Model    First Name    Last Name
---------------------------------
235      John          Smith
765      John          Smith
543      John          Smith
723      Jane          Doe
354      Jane          Doe
976      Bill          Evans
```

If Model was in one table and Names were in another this would be much simpler but I'm not sure how to go about this when they are in the same table.

========================================

Edited to clarify.

I need to get each model with a channel_id 15 from channel_data

For each model I need to look up the entry_id in channel_titles to find the author_id

I need to find the row with that author_id AND channel_id 4 in channel titles (each row with channel_id 4 has a unique author_id).

I need to take the entry_id of this row back to channel_data and get the first_name and last_name to go with the model.

I am well aware that the data is not structured well but that is what I have to work with. I am trying to accomplish a very small task in a much larger system, remodelling the data is not an option at this point.

I think sub-queries might be what I am looking for but this is not my area at all usually.

Comment: Is there also a AUTHORS table with columns `author_id` and `first_name` and `last_name` ?

Comment: I don't see anything that relates `author_id` (e.g. `101`) in `channel_titles` to the authors in `channel_data` (e.g. `John Smith`)

Comment: @Abra no there isn't and I'm not able to change the data, it's part of a larger legacy system.

Comment: @Nick the entry_id in channel_titles and channel_data is common

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MySQL tag added

Comment: @TimPrint but how are you supposed to know that `channel_id` 4 refers to first and last names?

Comment: @Nick edited for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that is convoluted. However, based on your description, this query should give you the results you want. The `WHERE` and `JOIN` descriptions follow the logic you have described in your question.

```
SELECT cd1.model, cd2.first_name, cd2.last_name
FROM channel_data cd1
JOIN channel_titles ct1 ON ct1.entry_id = cd1.entry_id
JOIN channel_titles ct2 ON ct2.channel_id = 4 AND ct2.author_id = ct1.author_id
JOIN channel_data cd2 ON cd2.entry_id = ct2.entry_id
WHERE cd1.channel_id = 15
ORDER BY cd1.entry_id
```

Output:

```
model   first_name  last_name
235     John        Smith
765     John        Smith
543     John        Smith
723     Jane        Doe
354     Jane        Doe
976     Bill        Evans
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cc428/2)

Comment: Thank you. The actual data is more complex but the principle scales up perfectly. It is working just as I needed it to. I very rarely need to write SQL queries but I have definitely learnt from this.